# Does wordpress come with htaccess

Tags: wordpress

does wordpress come with a htaccess file? I have my file zilla showing all files but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You may be interested to know about wordpress.stackexchange.com, where your question would be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

No, a freshly installed WordPress won't have a `.htaccess` set up yet.

Also, some servers have them set as hidden, so you won't be able to view them via plain FTP. I use this script I made to check if there's a `.htaccess` and if there is, to display its contents. Save it as `ht.php` and upload it then browse to it to see.

```
<pre>
<?php
$filename = ".htaccess";

if (file_exists($filename))
{
    $handle   = @fopen($filename, "rb");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    $data     = explode("\n", $contents);
    fclose($handle);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) 
    {
        echo htmlspecialchars($data[$i], ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<b>Error:</b> No such file found';
}
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Ok I went to my site www.khopon.com/ht.php and it had this message "Error: No such file found" . I assume that means no I do not have a .htaccess file?

Comment: @MurphDoggyDog: Yes, no `.htaccess`; you should be able to make one through your WordPress admin area when you configure your permalink settings.